# Question concerning a self-injective algebra and a faithful module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I'd like to know how corollary 2.11 of http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930098726X# follows from theorem 2.10 from the same reference.

1) I know that $A$ being self-injective implies that every projective module is injective, but $M$ is only a faithful module...does $M$ have to have the form $Ae$? or does this have something to do with Proposition 2.4 (Morita equivalence of some endomorphism rings)?

2) $A$ can be viewed as a submodule of $M^r$, but why is $A$ in $\mathfrak{add}\ M$ ?

3) How does $A=\text{End}(M_B)$ follow ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Questions are cheap: do you mind not asking five questions at once? I'm pretty sure this would be better in at least three parts.

Comment: Faithfulness of $M$ means we have ses $0\to A\to M^r \to C\to 0$ (where $C$ is the cokernel of the injection).  Self-injectivity of $A$ means that this ses splits and in particular $add(M)=add(A)$.  The final question follows from the theorem (Double centraliser property of $A$ and $B$)

Comment: @ Aaron In my mind, an $A$-module $M$ is faithful if for all $a,b \in A$, there exists $m \in M$ such that $am \neq bm$, can you tell me how to use this definition get the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow M^r \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$? Another question: If $A$ is self-injective,then the exact sequence splits, and we can get $A \in add(M)$, so $add(A) \subseteq add(M)$, but how to get $add(A) = add(M)$? Thank you.